# C++ dynamically creating a certain type from template

Tags: c++

I have a template

```
enum MyEnum = {MyEnum _1, MyEnum _2, ...};
template<MyEnum T>
struct MyStruct {
    ...
}
```

Now I would like to create a specific type of the template based on a condition. However, there is an open number of elements in MyEnum, so I can't do it via some sort of switch.

So I am looking for a way to do something like

```
void doStuff() {
    MyEnum e = getType();
    MyStruct<e> s;
}
```

But the compiler is complaining that e is not a constant expression. It makes sense why it does that since I am having runtime information. Is there a way to elegantly construct something that mimics

```
doStuff() {
    MyEnum e = getType();
    Switch(e) {
        case MyEnum_1: 
            MyStruct<MyEnum_1> s;
            ....
        case MyEnum_2: ...
    ...
}
```

Reason is, as mentioned before, the list of enums may get extended/changed regularly and I prefer to not have to maintain code on other ends every time that happens.

Comment: This cannot be done. C++ does not work this way. A template instance is defined at compile time, not run time. You have to use a `switch`, or a logical equivalent.

Comment: Yes, there's a technique described in [this proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0376r0.html) and [the author's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fjw7NjndQ50). By providing the upper and lower bounds on the possible values, you can receive the runtime value as a constant expression in a parameter (more accurately, in its type). The actual technique doesn't have all that much detail, but AFAIK, it's all but required to implement `std::visit`, so maybe some `variant` implementation articles would have more.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this should work:

```
MyStruct<decltype(e)> var;
```